# How to Remove Extra characters from the column Value using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to Map the values from the dictionary, where if the Field values matches with the dictionary it must remove all the extra values from the same. However i can match the things but how i can remove the extra charaters from the column.

Input Data

```
col_data

Indi8
United states / 08
UNITED Kindom (55)
ITALY 22
israel
```

Expected Output:

```
col_data

India
United States
United Kindom
Italy
Israel
```

Script i am using :

```
match_val=['India','United Kingdom','Israel','United States','Italy']

lower = [x.lower() for x in match_val]
def nearest(s):
    idx = np.argmax([SequenceMatcher(None, s.lower(), i).ratio() for i in lower])
    return np.array(match_val)[idx]

df['col_data'] = df['col_data'].apply(nearest)
```

The above script matches the vales with the List, But not able to remove the extra characters from the same. How i can modify the script so that it can remove the extra characters as well after mapping.

Answer (score 1):

I like this `str.extract` approach:

```py
df['col_data'] =  df['col_data'].str.extract(r'([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*)').str.title()
```

The regex `([A-Za-z]+(?: [A-Za-z]+)*)` will match all all-letter words from the start of the column, omitting all content at the end which you want to remove.

Comment: Did you mean `[0].str.title()` at the end instead of `str.title` at the beginning? Still it doesn't give `India` for the first one as the code doesn't use `match_val` list..